# I have to bring a photo from my desktop to my web page but i am facing problems?

Tags: javascript, html, websecurity

The problem I am facing is that I cannot seem to fix the error that comes to me stating "Not allowed to load local resource:" I do not know how to fix it
I don't believe that there's a problem with my code but here is the javascript code:

```
`const photoContainer = document.getElementById("photoContainer");

const photoDirectoryPath = "file:///D:/path1/Photo1"; // Replace with your actual path
const specificPhotoName = "1.jpg"; // Replace with the specific photo name

function fetchPhoto() {
  fetch(photoDirectoryPath + "/" + specificPhotoName)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = event.target.result;`your text`
        photoContainer.innerHTML = "";
        photoContainer.appendChild(img);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error("Error fetching photo:", error));
}

fetchPhoto();`
```

and here is the html code :

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Photo Display</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test_bed.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="photoContainer"></div>

  <script src="test_bed.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

and CSS:
`#photoContainer {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin-top: 20px;
border:3px solid #2a06f4;
height: 400px;
width: 400px
}

```
#photoContainer img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}`
```

I've tried to Temporarily Disable Security Restrictions and tried Using Local Servers like Visual Studio Code

Comment: Don't use fetch for local files. Use the HTML5 drag n drop API instead

Comment: I am not sure why you need to read the bytes of your file, just set the href of your image.  I am not sure you need to use fetch here. There are probably more direct ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: if you have Python installed, you can try to run `python3 -m http.server 9000` in your `D:/path1` folder. So`fetch` will work and you will have access to the pictures by  `http://localhost:9000/Photo1/1.jpg` url